# How do I "Get Info" from the command line?

Tags: command-line

Related to this question: https://superuser.com/q/514528/90435

Via http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/12/find-out-where-a-file-was-downloaded-from/ I find out that you can use 'get info' though Finder to find out where a file was downloaded from.

For example -
[image]

Now - my question is - can I get the same information from the command line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`mdls` lists the metadata attributes of a given file. Try this:

```
mdls -name kMDItemWhereFroms filename
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article about command line tricks](http://osxdaily.com/2012/12/05/9-command-line-tricks-for-mac-os-x-you-should-know/) you can do the following:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV* 'select LSQuarantineDataURLString from LSQuarantineEvent' | grep YOURFILENAME
```

Just exchange YOURFILENAME with the file you want to check.